# How to get data (items) from eBay Finding API through Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, ebay-api

I was trying to retrieve data from eBay Finding API through Google App Engine for a project. It seems to have to do with Google App Engine blocking regular requests.

I tried using `urlfetch` and `urllib3` but to no avail. I am trying to retrieve item data in JSON format.

This was my first attempt:

```
def get(self):
        requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine.monkeypatch()
        http = urllib3.PoolManager()
        key = 'WailSahb-Analysis-PRD-4c970d9ce-c9a80d1e'
        search_term = 'laptop'
        url = ('http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1\
    ?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords\
    &sortOrder=PricePlusShippingLowest\
    &buyerPostalCode=92128&SERVICE-VERSION=1.13.0\
    &SECURITY-APPNAME=' + key +
    '&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON\
    &REST-PAYLOAD\
    &itemFilter(0).name=Condition\
    &itemFilter(0).value=New\
    &itemFilter(1).paramName=Currency\
    &itemFilter(1).paramValue=EUR\
    &itemFilter(2).paramName=FeedbackScoreMin\
    &itemFilter(2).paramValue=10\
    &paginationIntput.entriesPerPage=100\
    &outputSelector(0)=SellerInfo\
    &descriptionSearch=FALSE\
    &paginationIntput.pageNumber=1\
    &keywords=' + search_term)
        url = url.replace(" ", "%20")
        result = http.request('GET', url)
        self.response.write(result)
```

With this approach I get the following error:

> MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pages.ebay.com', port=443):
>   Max retries exceeded with url:
>   /messages/page_not_found.html?eBayErrorEventName=p4buoajkbnmbehq%60%3C%3Dosu71%2872%3A4505-2018.08.16.15.28.47.151.MST (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(13, 'Permission
>   denied')))

I also tried this approach:

```
def get(self):
        try:
            api = Connection(appid='WailSahb-Analysis-PRD-4c970d9ce-c9a80d1e', config_file=None)
            response = api.execute('findItemsAdvanced', {'keywords': 'legos'})

            assert(response.reply.ack == 'Success')
            assert(type(response.reply.timestamp) == datetime.datetime)
            assert(type(response.reply.searchResult.item) == list)

            item = response.reply.searchResult.item[0]
            assert(type(item.listingInfo.endTime) == datetime.datetime)
            assert(type(response.dict()) == dict)
            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
            self.response.write(result.data)
        except ConnectionError as e:
            self.response.write(e.response.dict())
```

In which I get this error:

> TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of
>   type

Could anyone please help me get through this.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Maybe you should delete the private keys or IDs because of being sensitive information.

Comment: Look, since /messages/page_not_found.html?eBayErrorEventName=p4buoaj···, it looks like you are hitting the wrong page or the correct page but wrongly in some way. It doesn't looks at all as Google App Engine blocking regular requests. Have you solved your problem already?

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel like my answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I tried to reproduce your problem and had to change a few things, but was eventually able to successfully get the page you're trying to request.

I first copied your first attempt verbatim, and the error I got was slightly different:

> `MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pages.ebay.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /messages/page_not_found.html?eBayErrorEventName=p4buoajkbnmbehq%60%3C%3Dsm%7E71%287147606-2018.08.23.14.59.22.829.MST (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",))`

This indicated to me that the that the issue was a missing or invalid SSL module. You didn't share your `app.yaml`, but I had to add the following to mine to get the HTTPS request to succeed:

```
libraries:
- name: ssl
  version: latest
```

However, the eventual app engine response was incorrect, because `result` was a `urllib3.response.HTTPResponse` object, and not an actual response.

To fix this, I changed the line:

```
self.response.write(result)
```

to

```
self.response.write(result.content)
```

and then this worked as intended.

---

Here's the final versions of the files that made this work for me:

In `app.yaml`:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: ssl
  version: latest
```

In `main.py`:

```
import webapp2
from requests_toolbelt.adapters import appengine
import urllib3


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        appengine.monkeypatch()
        http = urllib3.PoolManager()
        key = 'WailSahb-Analysis-PRD-4c970d9ce-c9a80d1e'
        search_term = 'laptop'
        url = (
            'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1\
            ?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords\
            &sortOrder=PricePlusShippingLowest\
            &buyerPostalCode=92128&SERVICE-VERSION=1.13.0\
            &SECURITY-APPNAME=' + key +
            '&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON\
            &REST-PAYLOAD\
            &itemFilter(0).name=Condition\
            &itemFilter(0).value=New\
            &itemFilter(1).paramName=Currency\
            &itemFilter(1).paramValue=EUR\
            &itemFilter(2).paramName=FeedbackScoreMin\
            &itemFilter(2).paramValue=10\
            &paginationIntput.entriesPerPage=100\
            &outputSelector(0)=SellerInfo\
            &descriptionSearch=FALSE\
            &paginationIntput.pageNumber=1\
            &keywords=' + search_term)
        url = url.replace(" ", "%20")
        result = http.request('GET', url)
        self.response.write(result.data)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```